# keras.models.load_model() fails to load model from .keras file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hello so i am trying to load model from .keras zip file but it fails to do so. it gives me this error. how can i fix it?

```py
modelvggNew = keras.models.load_model('/kaggle/working/vgg15.keras')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[33], line 1
----> 1 keras.models.load_model('/kaggle/working/vgg15.keras')

File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_api.py:185, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    183     return legacy_h5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath)
    184 elif str(filepath).endswith(".keras"):
--> 185     raise ValueError(
    186         f"File not found: filepath={filepath}. "
    187         "Please ensure the file is an accessible `.keras` "
    188         "zip file."
    189     )
    190 else:
    191     raise ValueError(
    192         f"File format not supported: filepath={filepath}. "
    193         "Keras 3 only supports V3 `.keras` files and "
   (...)
    202         "might have a different name)."
    203     )

ValueError: File not found: filepath=/kaggle/working/vgg15.keras. Please ensure the file is an accessible `.keras` zip file.
```

Even tho filepath exists it fails to load

Comment: If the file exists, then the path you're supplying is incorrect. You can check with `os.path.isfile()`